# select records having maximum count of a field

Tags: mysql, sql

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT MaxTable.Customer,
       MaxTable.Product,
       Count(MaxTable.Product) AS CountOfProduct
FROM MaxTable
GROUP BY MaxTable.Customer, MaxTable.Product
```

This will create a derived table and i want to call it Product_count_query

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT Product_count_query.Customer,
       Max(Product_count_query.CountOfProduct) AS MaxOfCountOfProduct
FROM Product_count_query
GROUP BY Product_count_query.Customer;
```

This will create a derived table and i want to call it max_customer_count

QUERY 3:

```
SELECT Product_count_query.Customer,
       Product_count_query.Product,
       Product_count_query.CountOfProduct
FROM Max_Customer_Count
INNER JOIN Product_count_query ON 
       (Max_Customer_Count.MaxOfCountOfProduct = Product_count_query.CountOfProduct) AND
       (Max_Customer_Count.Customer = Product_count_query.Customer);
```

I want to combine these three queries in one to get results like this

```
Customer Name   Products with max number
```

My sample table is

```
Customer Product
James Keyboard
James Monitor
James Keyboard
```

Output table would be (if James has bought 2 keyboards and 1 monitor)

Customer Product   Countof product
    James Keyboard    2

If there is tie in number of products bought then both product name and count of product should be concatenated using comma separator.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here. If I'm reading your question right, you can get what you want with a single query using COUNT() and a GROUP BY clause. You've shown the sample table; please [edit] to include the output you'd like to get from that table. While you're at it, add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality can differ between them and therefore it's relevant to the answers.

Comment: My output table should have customer name and corresponding product name with max count. For example James has bought 2 keyboard and 1 monitor. So result should be

Comment: James     Keyboard    2

Comment: I need to show for every customer the product he has selected most often

Comment: As I asked before, [edit] your post and add those details there instead of burying them in comments. See how you posted your sample table? Post the sample output you want, in the same way you posted the sample table, so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `ROW_NUMBER` window function so,

Try this

```
SELECT Customer,
       Group_concat(Product separator ','),
       Group_concat(CountOfProduct separator ',')
FROM   (SELECT MaxTable.Customer,
               MaxTable.Product,
               Count(MaxTable.Product) AS CountOfProduct
        FROM   MaxTable
        GROUP  BY MaxTable.Customer,
                  MaxTable.Product) a
WHERE  CountOfProduct = (SELECT Max(CountOfProduct)
                         FROM   (SELECT MaxTable.Customer,
                                        MaxTable.Product,
                                        Count(MaxTable.Product) AS CountOfProduct
                                 FROM   MaxTable
                                 GROUP  BY MaxTable.Customer,
                                           MaxTable.Product) b
                         WHERE  a.Customer = b.Customer)
GROUP  BY Customer
```

use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate the result when there is a tie

Comment: Star!! thank heaps. one more help, if there is tie, say one customer bought 2 keyboard and 2 monitor then i want to see keyboard+monitor. How to get that?

Comment: @RoleeSatyam The query already does that. When there is a tie between two product for a customer then it will return both the products

Comment: yes it does but i was wondering if i can concatenate both results in one?

Comment: @RoleeSatyam What about the count then? Do you want to sum the count or concatenate or average or what?

Comment: concatenate the count too

Comment: @RoleeSatyam - Updated check now

Comment: @RoleeSatyam: If you would edit your post as I've asked, we'd know what you want for output and you'll get an answer much faster. Please do so instead of asking for changes in comments to answers. It also makes your question more useful to future readers who might have the same problem.